# sorting a unique vector in R

Tags: r

I have imported an csv data that contains notes from A to H and DEF, so i'm sorting all the notes within a vector so i can do my loop as vec[i], but i'm facing a problem while doing this following code that usually work on other data:

```
vec=sort(unique(data[,grep('note',colnames(data))]))
```

here is the output as you can see it is not unique which is abnormal:

```
> vec
 [1] A    A    A    B    B    B    C    C    C    D    D    D    DEF  DEF  E    E    E    F    F    F    G    G   
[23] G    H    H   
Levels: A A   A    B B   B    C C   C    D D   D    DEF DEF  E E   E    F F   F    G G   G    H H
```

I've also got this error message while trying to merge with another table that has the same notation :

> Unequal factor levels: coercing to character R

here is a print of a part of my data as you can see some note are not in line while on excel they are all the same:

```
7     5230380    29/04/2016  D    2016
11    5175661    25/04/2016  C    2016
12    1091429    24/05/2016  D    2016
13    1315190    02/06/2016  E    2016
14    3901166    30/03/2016  A    2016
15    5230046    22/03/2016  B    2016
16    9305302    04/04/2016  B    2016
17    1826276    11/05/2016  G    2016
18    9326295    26/04/2016  B    2016
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: A reproducible example would be much more helpful here. (Please leave the formatting as I've edited it.)

Comment: Clearly,  you have extra blank spaces.  Try `vec = gsub('\\s', '', as.character(vec))`

Comment: To elaborate on joran's comment. It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at this post; [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Note: I've edited the sample data assuming alignment issues, but as other commenters have pointed out, if you have leading or trailing spaces surrounding the letters, that will be a source of spurious "duplicates".

Comment: The thing is you are calling unique on a matrix/dataframe. Which should not be the case. unlist it first. `vec=sort(unique(unlist(data[,grep('note',colnames(data))])))`

Comment: Something like `vec=sort(unique(sub("\\s+", "", as.character(data[,grep('note',colnames(data))]))))` to remove spaces before `unique` is applied.

Comment: @Onyambu, thank you for your answer i've tried it and I still get the same problem vec=sort(unique(unlist(data[,grep('note',colnames(data))])))
> vec
 [1] A    A    A    B    B    B    C    C    C    D    D    D    DEF  DEF  E    E    E    F    F    F    G    G   
[23] G    H    H   
Levels: A A   A    B B   B    C C   C    D D   D    DEF DEF  E E   E    F F   F    G G   G    H H

Comment: @G5W Can i do the same vec = gsub('\\s', '', as.character(vec)) for data$note column maybe the problem come from it ?

Comment: @joran so i need to remove spaces  from data$note column? sorry if my question is stupid i'm still new in R

Comment: try doing As you can see there are different levels for `A` meaning that there are trailing spaces included. You have to trim them `trimws(as.character(vec))`

Comment: @S.ben  Yes   you can do that to any column to remove extra spaces in the names.

Comment: @MKR Thank you it works but that does not change the space within the note column

Comment: @Onyambu it works, thank you so much